# removing unwanted tags from html body with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have inherited some legacy HTML in which it has the following elements in the body of the code:

```
style

meta

title
```

How do i remove these with jQuery?

Comment: "...which it has the following tags in the body..." - which tags would they be?

Comment: Also, you might want to just consider doing a search for all those tags and stripping them out of the raw code instead of running a script after the DOM has loaded, although jQuery would be the quick fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can find a proper CSS selector to get to the elements you can simply detach them from the DOM:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('style, meta, title').detach();
});
```

I highly doubt you really want to detach the `<title>` element, though.

Answer (score 1):

`$('style, meta, title').remove();`

This would remove all of the specified elements from the DOM.

P.S. Make sure this is contained in the `$(document).ready()`, as is good practice for most jQuery code you will have to write.

Comment: They're called elements, not tags.